# How to get current item index in v-carousel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the following code that cycles a carousel which is fine but I want to be able to display the item title underneath as appose to on top of the image. I figured the way to do this is to create a new data value that is updated each time the carousel changes. I cannot figure out how to do this however.

```
<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in servicesCarouselItems"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
  >

  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
<v-card-title class="justify-center">{{currentTitle}}</v-card-title>


<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
      currentTitle: '',
      servicesCarouselItems: [
        {
          name: "Title1",
          src: require('../../1.jpeg'),
        },
        {
          name: "Title2",
          src: require('../../2.jpeg'),
        },
        {
          name: "Title3",
          src: require('../../3.jpeg'),
        }
      ],
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should take a look at `v-carousel` `input` event listener

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using the v-on:change / @change Vue event as shown in the example below.

```
<v-carousel @change="currentTitle = servicesCarouselItems[$event].name">
  <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in servicesCarouselItems"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
  >

  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

Further reading for those interested: 
https://renatello.com/get-selected-value-on-change-in-vuejs/#The_advantages_of_using_change_event_instead_of_v-model_binding

Comment: You need to an explanation why your answer addresses the original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

Propably best way is to use `v-model` - index of current item is exposed there...

```html
<v-carousel v-model="currentIndex">
  <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in servicesCarouselItems"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
  >

  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
<v-card-title class="justify-center">{{ currentTitle }}</v-card-title>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
      currentIndex: 0,
      servicesCarouselItems: [
        {
          name: "Title1",
          src: require('../../1.jpeg'),
        },
        {
          name: "Title2",
          src: require('../../2.jpeg'),
        },
        {
          name: "Title3",
          src: require('../../3.jpeg'),
        }
      ],
  }),
  computed: {
    currentTitle() {
      return this.servicesCarouselItems[this.currentIndex].name
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped. In the end it was 'v-on:change' I was looking for. To show this I've answered my own question.

Comment: @change is a Vue event not Vuetify :)